# Scala: Search element of string List inside map(List<String>, Int)

Tags: scala

In `MyMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[List[String], Int]()` 
I have to match  string inside MyMap, and get the value of corresponding Int. List of string represent topic of interest of my device, int is ID of device.

Comment: `myMap.find(_._1.contains("target")).map(_._2)`

Comment: @jwvh thanks for answer. .map return option like this Some(int) or none, work perfectly when list contains "target" for unique int. What about return array with all int that have same "target" in its list?

Comment: you should try to get it done by yourself first, and then explain what you've tried and the errors/problem you found

Answer (score 1):

Why don't yo use a filter, it do the same as find, but returning all the elements which satisfies the predicate

```
myMap.filter(_._1.contains("target")).map(_._2)
```

or even

```
myMap.filter(_._1.contains("target")).values
```